# A start job is running for dev-disk by \x2duuid : error take 1min 30s to boot Debian

Tags: debian, boot

I have multiboot Debian with others Unix/linux distro. During the boot process ,i get the following error:

```
A start job is running for dev-disk by \x2duuid-.....1min:30 s
Dependencies failed for swap
```

After `1min : 30 s` the boot process continued without problem , How to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can reproduced when you multi-boot linux systems with more than one  `swap` is  activated during linux install, to solve this issue run the following command to find out the UUID of your swap partition:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Example of output ( `sda4` = your swap partition):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 27 13:16 cfa74c40-1234-4fee-a2d5-e8c789c629f0 -> ../../sda4
```

Edit your `fstab` and change the `uuid`:

Example:`nano /etc/fstab` :

```
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=f97a6afb-3447-4616-bfa3-123be50f9fa5 none   swap    sw      0     0
```

Re-create the `swap` partition and assign the new `uuid`:

```
swapoff /dev/sda4
mkswap -U cfa74c40-1234-4fee-a2d5-e8c789c629f0 /dev/sda4
swapon -a
```

If you have more than 1 swap partition, comment out the other swap partitions on your `fstab`.