# Debian 8 / kernel 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 failing on boot sometimes

Tags: debian, boot

I have an issue with some of our debian 8 servers. Sometimes our servers refuse to boot. We try to check some disk and memory issue but we found nothing. We think about a network issue (our server in the screen has many failover IPs), so we try to reduce the network configuration to the minimum (only lo and eth0 configuration). The network connectivity is working right (all alright in rescue mode and alright when the server success to boot).

Screenshot of the boot process
[image: Screenshot of the boot process]

Comment: What is the output of `blkid | grep "d7a\|3b1"`

Comment: I only have access to this server in rescue mode (It does not reboot anymore since this morning). Is it ok to execute this command in this mode ?

Comment: Got this :/dev/sda1: UUID="3b1dfaaf-5e23-4656-99d0-ad81ebc0cfbf" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="d7a25b78-0899-41e5-8b69-9aa82317365a" TYPE="swap"

Comment: to solve the problem caused by the swap (only the swap) see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319382/a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by-x2duuid-error-take-1min-30s-to-boot-de .