# Slow booting after dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I just installed Kali Linux (on /dev/sda5) in dual boot with Ubuntu (on /dev/sda2). However, now that I have Kali, Ubuntu takes a few minutes to launch, whereas Kali takes a few seconds, and I would like the contrary. How can I do that ?

## EDIT 1

- Ubuntu took about 20 seconds to launch before I installed the dual boot.
- I have updated Grub on both partitions, so it looks different if I choose to boot with Ubuntu or Kali in the BIOS.
- The step that seems to take the more time (about two thirds of the time) shows :
  `a start job is running for dev-disk-by\...a-lot-of-characters...\.device`

## EDIT 2

Editing my `fstab` to have the correct UUID for my swap partition only reduced by half the booting time: Ubuntu still takes a good 45 seconds to launch: so my question is not a duplicate of the questions suggested.

## EDIT 3

Rebuilding my initramfs (`sudo update-initramfs -u`) and then updating grub (`sudo update-grub`) did the job: now Ubuntu takes only 10 seconds to launch. Thanks everyone!

Comment: how long did ubuntu take to boot before you installed kali?

Comment: Did you reinstall grub? - does the OS selection screen look different?

Comment: What's taking the time? You should be able to see the boot process by removing 'quiet splash' from the grub line that is booting (press `e` when it comes to the OS selection screen and remove the words 'quiet splash' this will be a one time change to your system so rebooting will be however it is now).

Comment: Sorry Thomas but I found no answer there

Answer (score 2):

*(I would have rather posted a comment asking for more information, but I can't, so...)*

You probably change some of your partitions during the installation process and now your system is trying to mount a partition that no longer exists, or some other impossible thing, until the job finally timeouts and gives up You should edit your `/etc/fstab` according to your current partitions, that you can check in a variety of ways(`fdisk`, `lsblk`, etc).

[This question looks very similar to yours and may be exactly your problem(since your system boots, it wasn't a very important partition that failed, maybe swap?).](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319382/a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by-x2duuid-error-take-1min-30s-to-boot-de)

[In this question they even suggest gparted, which has a graphical interface, to check partitions if you prefer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by)

Comment: Editing my `fstab` and then rebuilding my `initramfs` did the job, and now Ubuntu takes only 10 seconds to launch. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Glad to help! It bothers me a little that this question got marked as duplicate of that question. This problem is not that related to Kali Linux, but to a problem during installation that could have happened in other distros. There may be a duplicate, but no the one that was marked.

Comment: Yes, I would like this marking as duplicate to be removed...